# Count elements and return them

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I want to count the elements in a list and return a list containing the elements paired with them respective quantity

Something like that:

Input:
`(count-elements '(a b d d a b c c b d d))`

Output:
`((a 2) (b 3) (d 4) (c 2))`

How can I do it? I'm not having any success trying to pair the element and its accounting

Comment: You should add your previous efforts to the question. Maybe you go more into detail what exactly causes you problems here. :)

Comment: If you were given `((a 1) (b 3) (d 4) (c 2))` and the symbol `a`, how would you produce a fresh list `((a 2) (b 3) (d 4) (c 2))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can be divided into three broad parts:

1. Duplicate recognition/ deletion : This can be done by either removing all the duplicates of every element, or by knowing that the current element is a duplicate(and thus not counting it as a new element.). This(the former strategy) can be done by using the function [`remove-duplicates`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rm_dup.htm)
2. Counting: A way to actually *count* the elements. This can be done by the function [`count`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_countc.htm)
3. Combination: A way to combine the results into a list. This can be done by the macro [`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm).

The Code:

```
(defun count-elements (lst)
  (loop for i in (remove-duplicates lst)
        with ans = nil
        do (push (list i (count i lst)) ans)
        finally (return ans)))

CL-USER> (count-elements '(a a b c))
((C 1) (B 1) (A 2))
CL-USER> (count-elements '(a b c d d a b s a c d))
((D 3) (C 2) (A 3) (S 1) (B 2))
CL-USER>
```

**NOTE**:  The result might not be arranged as you would expect, because of the value returned by  `remove-duplicates`

---

**EDIT:** As pointed out by coredump, a better version of `count-elements` would be:

```
(defun count-elements (lst)
  (map 'list
       (lambda (e)
         (list e (count e lst)))
       (remove-duplicates lst)))
```

which, instead of using [`loop`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/m_loop.htm), uses [`map`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map.htm).

Comment: If you use remove-duplicates, the combination can be expressed as a map: `(map 'list (lambda (e) (list e (count e sequence))) (remove-duplicates sequence))`